# Reading CAN Bus without a ground

Tags: grounding, can, logic-analyzer

I need your help to find a transceiver that can read or write data on a CAN bus using only CANH and CANL, without the ground of the System I am connected to.

Just to be clear, I need something that can work like a normal CAN tool like Vektor or PEAK that can read data from the CAN bus without the ground signal.

Something like that:

PC <--[USB, Supply, GND]--> uC <--[Tx, Rx, Supply, GND]--> Transceiver <--[CANH, CANL]--> System

A normal transceiver doesn't work, as I need to unify the ground between the system and my PC. I have been looking for an isolated CAN transceiver with two separate grounds, but I think they need some additional circuitry.

What do you think? Do you know a component that might help?

Comment: "*as I need to unify the ground between the system and my PC*" What do you mean by this? Normally you would do this by  connecting the grounds. What is the reason the grounds can't be connected? Please be more specific about why you are limited by the ground. Does the common mode even drift that far away between the two devices? How long is the run?

Comment: The idea is to connect the two CANH/L pins and let the uC to acquire data flowing on the bus. In real situations, with a normal transceiver, You need to connect together the ground (let's call it GND1) of the supply given by the PC and the ground (GND2) of the system from which I'm reading the data. Vector tools for CAN analyzing, for example, are able to do it without having GND2 as input

Comment: That doesn't answer what I was asking. That's just describing the normal situation for CAN. I am asking you to describe *your* situation. For example, is this a fixed setup with something funny about the grounds? If so, what is funny and what parts can be modified? Or is this supposed to be a diagnostic tool that needs to hook into a variety of setups that cannot be modified? Is it just a no need of a ground enough or do you actually need isolation?

Comment: You should be able to make one with an opto-isolator. If I understand correctly, a 1 bit gives you 2V between CANH and CANL, and a 0 bit gives you 0V

Comment: The situation that I described is my situation. I should be able to read CAN Bus in any generic system just using CANH/L without ground

Comment: Stick an opto between transceiver and MCU then. You will need an isolated supply for the transceiver.

Comment: @DKNguyen CAN is more than able to drive an opto without isolated supplies. The opto needs to be a led-to-photodiode type then, and you need a bit of gain to get the signal, but this is not a big problem with excellent op-amps available today. The LED current can be pretty low while the thing remains functional. The best I could make on the breadboard was 50uA LED drive, with a shaping network to compensate the parasitics and make the current through the led nice and square.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica But without an isolated supply what's going to power the transceiver? I assume we're talking about different things. I think you're talking about putting an opto between the transceiver and the bus? I was talking about putting an opto between the MCU and the transceiver.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only receiving, this is not a hard problem. All you need is a suitable optoisolator, and an isolated DC/DC converter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f27fB6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The isolator could be a magnetic type, where instead of D1 there's a transmit coil, and the receive side has signal conditioning logic. With a LED-photodiode optoisolator, you'd use the application circuit on the receive side to condition the signal - or use an optoisolator with the receive conditioner already built in.

I've made such sniffers several times from discrete components for demonstration purposes, heatshrinking the IR LED and photodiode together. If you can get a good gain on the photodiode, the DC/DC converter and the LED driver transistor are unnecessary: you can drive a high-efficiency IR LED directly through a 10kOhm resistor. C1 has to be selected to compensate somewhat for the LED's parasitic capacitance - ideally try for lowest junction capacitance LED you can get at a reasonable efficiency.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCeQkB.png)</sup>

OA1 is a suitable rail-to-rail I/O transimpedance amplifier with 1mV/uA output. Another gain stage would be needed, followed by a comparator, to produce the RX signal.

Answer (score 0):

> *I need your help to find a transceiver that can read or write data on
> a CAN bus using only CANH and CANL, without the ground of the System I
> am connected to.*

As far as I'm aware, CAN bus voltages are centred around +2.5 volts so, **without** a GND connection you cannot raise the data lines to have this nominal centre-voltage: -

[image]

Image from [Exploring the CANbus with an oscilloscope](https://www.testandmeasurementtips.com/exploring-canbus-oscilloscope/). And similarly from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ISO11898-3_Waveform.svg): -

[image]

Comment: That last image doesn't resemble an actual CAN bus signal. In the recessive state the bus is undriven; CAN HI and CAN LO are pulled to the same voltage by the terminating resistor(s). The first image is accurate. Also, CAN transceivers can tolerate at least a few volts common mode offset, signals are not required to be centered at 2.5V

Comment: @user28910 it may not be accurate but, the point is that with two wires and no ground, you cannot hope to bias both lines at circa 2.5 volts with respect to CANbus GND.

Comment: What I meant was that if you look at actual CAN bus signals on a scope, it will look like the upper image, and not like the lower one.  In the recessive state, CAN_H and CAN_L are at the same voltage.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is impossible. CANH and CANL are referenced to ground, so a CAN transceiver can't work properly without a ground connection, or at least some other common mode reference. Not even an isolated CAN transceiver works without a common reference, nor building an isolated CAN interface with a standard CAN transceiver, isolating supply and opto-isolators.

The point of the isolation is to keep grounds separated when it is necessary (e.g. between PC and car) but the actual data transmission needs ground reference between transceivers on the bus.

If a floating supply is used on the isolating transceiver, then there might be tricks to keep the common mode within limits of possible data transmission without a ground connection, for example some CAN transceivers have a midpoint voltage reference for termination, but higher impedace resistors to midpoint reference might be good enough to allow common mode to be within limits of data reception.

Comment: All reasonable CAN implementations let you reference CANH to CANL without considering ground. It is a differential transmission, after all. Floating transceivers are no problem. Just because the CANH to CANL dominant state transmission is *implemented* by using switches to connect to VCC/GND respectively doesn't mean it's the only valid implementation. Of course, most transceiver implementations use the ground reference, but it's entirely possible to have a compliant implementation that doesn't. The ground reference is simply required by some implementations, not others.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica All reasonable CAN transceivers have a limit for common mode voltage. No matter how low or high it is, how can you guarantee without a common ground (or other reference) between devices that your CANH and CANL wires are within that common mode voltage limit compared to transceiver ground pin if it has a floating supply that may float at any voltage? Exceeding that may not do damage, but data reception is not guaranteed if it is exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to a CAN bus from a PC, why not just use a USB/CAN adapter that has isolation?  I'm not familiar with Vektor, but I'm pretty sure Peak has isolated adapters. There are other vendors as well. I've been using the Kvaser Leaf Light for years. I don't even bother to connect the CAN ground, CAN HI and CAN LO only works just fine